# Inserting data in an sqlserver using the column name from a control. c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to insert data in an `SQL` table by executing an Insert Query.

The problem is that I need to get the column name from a cell in the selected gridview Row.

Here's the snippet:

```
SqlCommand cmd30 = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable ( '"+GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text+"' , r_id) values ('"+ GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text +"', '"+TextBox1.Text+"')",con30);
cmd30.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**r_id** is not a Primary Key.

Error is:

`Incorrect syntax near 'r_id'.`

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `SqlCommand Parameters` to resolve this issue.

Comment: COnsidered - ah - looking at the SQL that you generate and then fixcing the bug? That is an obvious error the moment you (a) READ the error instead of copy / pasting it and (b) look at the sql you have generated. Which is what a debugger helps with.

Comment: @EdiG. This is one of the cases where parameters DO NOT WORK becasue parameters can not contain object names.

Comment: @user3527503: can you post the generatet statement: (cmd30.CommandText;)

Comment: can u suggest some other way of doing this? all i need to do is get column name from first cell of the selected row and insert data that is in the second cell of the selected row.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [SqlCommand Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Also make sure you get valid column name from `GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;`

**Code**:

```
string col1 = GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; 
string sql = "INSERT into mytable (" + col1 + ", r_id) Values (@" + col1 + ", @rid)";
SqlCommand cmd30 = new SqlCommand(sql, con30);
cmd30.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + col1, GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
cmd30.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rid", TextBox1.Text);    
cmd30.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. the snippet shows an error in the line -"cmd30.Parameters.AddWithValue(@r_id, TextBox1.Text); " under @r_id

Comment: I have updated answer, but can you tell what error says?

Comment: it shows a red line below @rid in the second last line. error is:"the name rid does not exist in current context".

Comment: sorry it should be enclosed in double quotes. Updated

Comment: @user3527503 just be very careful with code like this, if malicious users can modify the text of Cells[0] they could introduce sql injection attacks.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisMarisic.

Comment: hi..putting double quotes worked but now I am getting another error:"Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
Incorrect syntax near 'signals'"                                      "signals " here is a part of the column name that i get from GridView7.SelectedRow.Cells[0]

Comment: hi ...It worked...@Hassan Nisar  :Thanks Hassan for you help. was stuck with this issue for a long time  @ChrisMarisic : i will be careful with this..Thank you all....